# Css border smaller than 4px @300dpi using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: css, printing, wkhtmltopdf

I'm generating an auto-filled PDF, cloned from an inDesign layout that I was given. This layout uses tables, with 0.5pt borders on tables. Those borders aren't rendered properly when using wkhtmltopdf, since webkit doesn't want lines thinner than 0.8pt/1px.

I tried to use workarounds such as 0.8px (no display at 100% on screen, correct height at 400%), directly 0.5pt, or using 1px box shadows, none of this seem to give me the correct thickness, since sub-1px or sub-0.8pt lines aren't rendered into my PDF file, and 1px box-shadows give me the same issue.

Edit: The command I'm using to generate my PDF: `wkhtmltopdf.exe -T 0 -B 0 -L 0 -R 0 --dpi 300 --disable-smart-shrinking <input> <output>`

I'm not against an optical workaround.
Here's a preview of my issue:
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.
Impossible to do with CSS in case it's processed by wkhtmltopdf.

The first workaround I found was to render the page with zoom:1.41 in an A3 paper size, then render it at zoom:1/(1.41) in an A4. That was quite bloated.

So, I replaced my borders with  using a SVG sprite, with an height/width of 0.2mm. It allows me to skip the A4->A3->A4 conversion, and still use the --disable-smart-shrinking option, even if my markup is now ugly.

Comment: can you provide more info on this, like code or any reference link? I am also stuck at sort of similar issue

Comment: Hi,
I can't post a link since it's part of an internal system for one of my clients. I didn't use svg, but span elements with a gradient:

Markup:
`<span class="line_emu"></span>`

CSS: 
`display:block;width:100%;height:1.2pt;background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(255,255,255) 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 20%,rgb(130,128,130) 22%, rgb(0,0,0) 52%, rgb(130,128,130) 84%,rgb(255,255,255) 85%, rgb(255,255,255) 100%);`

I gave this a height in pt instead of px to avoid the decimal value <0.5 being stripped. Ugly, but works. Nobody renders this page except wkhtml.

@PavanJaju

Comment: Hello @Lucascvs ! Finally someone who has the same issue ! Nevertheless, I noticed that "alias" colours give the right behaviour (ie border: 1px solid black;). If I try with another color (#EBEBEB for example), I get the thicker border on the table. Did you find any "less ugly" solution ? I'm not quite sure how to implement your solution in order to get a full borders table... In any case, thank you.

Comment: @DavidB. Hi, I stopped using wkhtmltopdf for formats smaller than A3 since phantomJS/headless chrome renders better details & css transforms. But, to render tables with this method, I used before/after pseudo-elements on table, thead, tfoot, tr and tds to achieve those borders. I now try to avoid those hairlines on big formats.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I found was to scale all pixel values in the document by 2, then apply a css transform to scale it all down again to the correct size.

```
//original

body{ width: 210mm; }
p{ font-size:12px; }
.bordered{ border-width: 0.5px; ) //didn't work

//hacked

body{ width: 420mm; transform: scale(0.5); transform-origin: 0 0; }
p{ font-size:24px; }
.bordered{ border-width: 1px; }
```

The rendering engine must parse all values and round to the nearest integer before it performs the css transforms.

Obviously this works if you need a 0.5px line (whatever that means in the real world of print!). More granular control would require a larger scale ratio, which I haven't tried yet.

In theory it'd be fairly easy to set the body font size to some multiple of a normal value, then use rems to make the css easier on the eye and quicker to scale.

Edit:

I can confirm that scaling by 10x and then transforming down works really well to produce borders / lines accurate to 0.1px. Here's some scss:

```
$final_width: 210mm;
$final_height: 297mm;
$scale_factor: 10;

$page_width: #{$scale_factor * $final_width};
$page_height: #{$scale_factor * $final_height};

html{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: #{$scale_factor*10}px;
}

body{
    transform: scale(#{1/$scale_factor});
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    width: $page_width;
    height: $page_height;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: -$page_height;
```

...

The define all your layout sizes in rems: e.g. border: 0.05rem (0.5px end result, as 1rem = 10px in this case)

Answer (score 1):

My workaround for the time-being is to use box-shadow instead of border.

box-shadow: 1px 1px black

It's not perfect, but it is the only work-around I have found that avoids the thick borders in tables when converting html to pdf using wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: This works surprisingly well for when the border simply refuses to show up and a complete unit refactor is not going to happen. All sides: `box-shadow: 1px 1px black, -1px -1px black, 1px -1px black, -1px 1px black;`

Answer (score 0):

Setting a body width in CSS did it for me.

I had to set a width of 800px at 100 dpi to get 1px borders